# Javascript for-loop on json in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, internet-explorer-8

I am receiving some json looking like this (which is in the following stored in the var response):

```
    [{"complexity":"1","name":"Model1"}
,{"complexity":"2","name":"Model2"}]
```

to iterate it and to fill the names in a list within css ul tags named with the class *.model*

```
<ul class="model"></ul>
```

I'm using a simple foreach-loop. Which seeems to be totally ok in Firefox and IE9 (and greater). But in IE it's not working.
**(working in FF but not IE8)**

```
function(response) {
        response.forEach(function (model) {
            $('.model').append('<li>' + model['name'] +'</li>');
        });
```

That is why I tried the following options using jQuery v1.8.2 with no success:
**(working in FF but not IE8)**

```
jQuery.each(response, function(index, model){
          $('.model').append('<li>' + model['name'] +'</li>');
        });
```

Also using "map" did not do the trick
**(working in FF but not IE8)**

```
var a = jQuery.map(response, function(model){
          $('.model').append('<li>' + model['name'] +'</li>');
        });
```

According to my opinion the easiest way (and also most straight-forward) would be using a for-loop which is 
**(working in none of the two: neither FF nor IE8)**

```
var model;
        for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            model = reponse[i];
            $('.model').append('<li>' + model['name'] +'</li>');
        });
```

**also not working**

```
        for(var model in response) {
            $('.model').append('<li>' + model['name'] +'</li>');
        });
```

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? Any error in console?

Comment: My guess is that your problem lies within the HTML that you're appending rather than in the way you're iterating through the array. Is `.model` a `<ul>`?

Comment: It works here on IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/E6eD6/

Comment: Can you show us your ajax code?

Comment: <ul class="model"></ul>

Comment: jQuery version is v1.8.2

Comment: it seems like it's well-known that IE8 doesn not support foreach-loops but the suggested workaround is using either a $each or for-loops which is not working for me as well

Comment: @A.Wolff: your provided jsfiddle is not working on IE8. on IE 11 it is.

Comment: @Kai go there on IE8, should work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/E6eD6/show

Comment: @A.Wolff you're right. looks good - but what the heck is my problem then?

Comment: got it solved! was a really bad combination: foreach did not work but each did - but none of them did work local in IE (in FF it did) because I fetched the json via cross-side scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved! was a really bad combination: *forEach* did not work but *$.each* did - but none of them did work locally in IE (in FF it did) because I fetched the json via cross-side scripting which has to happen (according to IE8 standards) with the same protocol. locally it was file:// and http:// uploaded to my webspace the two matched.

Answer (score -2):

Your JSON looks like an array of objects. Use model.name instead of model[name]

Comment: OP is using `model['name']` which is fine

Comment: Oops. Didn't notice the quotes around name. That's on me. In hindsight that may be the side effect of some last night vodka.